How to fetch and view query profile from query_id in Snowflake?
Hi Snowflake Experts/Developers/Data Engineers, I want to view the query profile of a query_id.
Is it possible to view query profile from query_id?

If so how?
If its not possible:
is it possible to generate the explain plan of the same query from a query_id?

Thanks.
Background Story: I have a query, which took a lot of time, and the task, which used this query, was cancelled by Snowflake, as it exceeded 1 hour of execution time.
I suspect something is wrong with the stream, because if I try to fetch count of rows from the stream, it takes forever to return data. (The query profile of this simple select count(1) from my_stream showed huge number of rows being scanned and a lot of bytes spilled to local storage)
I wanted to check how the query is behaving and then blame the performance problem to the stream, so that I can change it from normal stream to an "append-only" stream.

In Snowflake UI, go to -
Monitoring > Query history> Filter >filter by query ID

But please note you have to have admin permission or permission to see query info for all users.

thanks a lot! I was able to figure it out finally!
